# Should I start a new ASP.Net MVC project with MVC 2 RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a new ASP.Net MVC application that I am about to start and I am wondering if its worth my while to use the 2 RC version over MVC 1.

Will my MVC 1 applications upgrade easily to MVC 2 if I do continue with 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you start it by using MVC 2 RC. If you decide to use MVC 1 and you haven't modified or extended anything too deeply in MVC 1 upgrading won't give you much pain.

But I think MVC 2 RC is reliable to start developing a new app. My 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your requirement MVC 2 is still beta but.

MVC 1 app can be upgrade to MVC 2 with lots of trouble, you can easily convert Uprade from  this link http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Comment: Why did you down vote I think I gave a proper explanation, correct me if I am wrong.